# setTimeout bug using iterations in IE/FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

Does anyone have a good technical reason why the following code runs fine in WebKit based browsers (Chrome/Safari) but causes FF to hang and IE never writes anything out? Note that if i use writeOutDirect() which does not use setTimeout() then it works fine (but has other side effects as i discuss at http://blog.livz.org/post/More-responsive-UI-with-setTimeout-on-WebKit.aspx .

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function doIteration() {
            for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
                writeOut(i);
                //writeOutDirect(i);                
            }

        }

        function writeOut(i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.write(i+'<br/>');
            },0);
        }

        function writeOutDirect(i) {
            document.write(i+'<br/>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doIteration()">

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gecko behavior here is correct.  The WebKit behavior is a bug.  See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65407

Answer (score 1):

The script you gave here does write out something, namely "0". `document.write()` will only add content to the document if it is called while the page is loading. If you call it after the page finished loading it will replace the current document by the content you gave it (a call to [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.open) is implied). And with the current document being gone all its timeouts are gone as well. So only one timeout gets a chance to run (the one writing out `0`), it replaces the document and all the other timeouts are canceled.

In Chrome replacing the current document via `document.open()` doesn't kill existing timeouts, they simply operate on the new document - that might be a bug, at the very least it is incompatible to all the other browsers. I'm not sure whether any existing standard clearly describes whether the timeouts need to be canceled in this case however.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference (and anyone who runs into this in future), if you use document.body.appendChild() rather than document.write everything works fine.... which probably suits most scenarios.